# PACT Testing with Golang

Tags: go, testing, pact

I am trying to set up a simple example test for PACT via Golang.
I have this example server:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/products", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        fmt.Fprintf(w, `[{"id": 1, "name": "Product 1", "price": 10.0}, {"id": 2, "name": "Product 2", "price": 20.0}]`)
    })

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

and I have this PACT-Test:

```
package main_test

import (
    "net/http"
    "testing"

    "github.com/pact-foundation/pact-go/dsl"
)

func TestPact_Provider(t *testing.T) {
    pact := &dsl.Pact{
        Consumer: "Consumer",
        Provider: "Provider",
        Host:     "localhost",
    }

    defer pact.Teardown()

    pact.AddInteraction().
        Given("test state").
        UponReceiving("a request for products").
        WithRequest(dsl.Request{
            Method: http.MethodGet,
            Path:   dsl.String("/products"),
        }).
        WillRespondWith(dsl.Response{
            Status: 200,
            Body:   dsl.Match([]interface{}{}),
        })

    if err := pact.Verify(func() error {
        // test your http client
        return nil
    }); err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Error on Verify: %v", err)
    }
}
```

but I get this error:

```
2023/04/06 10:09:57 [INFO] mock WARN: Please note: we are tracking events anonymously to gather important usage statistics like Pact-Ruby version and operating system. To disable tracking, set the 'PACT_DO_NOT_TRACK' environment variable to 'true'.
2023/04/06 10:09:57 [INFO] INFO  WEBrick 1.8.1
2023/04/06 10:09:57 [INFO] INFO  ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30) [x64-mingw-ucrt]
2023/04/06 10:09:57 [INFO] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=9704 port=51218
2023/04/06 10:09:57 [ERROR] service removal monitor failed to process signal: not supported by windows
--- FAIL: TestPact_Provider (10.92s)
panic: match: unhandled type: interface {} [recovered]
    panic: match: unhandled type: interface {}
```

I wasnt quite sure what was needed to set up a pact test. I have installed the pact broker, cli, mock service and provider verifier via gem. Is it needed to have the pact broker on docker as I read something in that direction?

Thank you for your help and greetings,